# Pyinstaller RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, recursion, pyinstaller

I got the following problem, that if I try to generate an exe using pyinstaller I get the following error message:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I found a lot of solutions saying that I should add

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
```

into the .spec file which is generated. Doing that the .exe is generated successfully. But if I then try to run the .exe I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres
```

Tried a lot of different solutions provided in other posts but none worked. Is there anybody who has an idea how to fix it? 
I'm using

```
PyInstaller: 3.6
Python: 3.7.6 (conda)
```

On Another computer I had an older version of Python and Pyinstaller installed and over there it worked perfectly fine with the same script.

Answer (score 0):

try the option --onefile. if possible try to simplify your code as best as possible, (e.g. use modules instead of individual files, etc)

Comment: On Another computer I had an older version of Python and Pyinstaller installed and over there it worked perfectly fine with the same script.